# How to refresh Image picture if I use CacheOption.OnLoad for BitmapImage WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, caching, bitmapimage

So I have an `<Image>` object which is a small box displaying choosed image by user.

Because he/she may change it often, I must to use BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad, so it is loaded to memory and file is not used by processed what was the problem before.

But now I have a problem to refresh this Image content if I change such a file.

Anyone may give me a hint how I can manage this situation. I have a code after user choose new image as below:

```
            ... changing file at pathToFileDestination
            BitmapImage imageBitmap = new BitmapImage();
            imageBitmap.BeginInit();
            imageBitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            imageBitmap.UriSource = new Uri(pathToFileDestination, UriKind.Absolute);      
            imageBitmap.EndInit();

            positionPicture.Source = null;
            positionPicture.Source = imageBitmap;
            ((PositionManagerWindow)this.Owner).positionPicture_image.Source = null;
            ((PositionManagerWindow)this.Owner).positionPicture_image.Source = imageBitmap;
```

I would like to reset my Image (display new picture) when user choose new image while being able to change the file of bitmap.

I hope you understand what I mean, if not please ask and specify what is not clear ?

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but since it would have helped me, maybe others like a solution, too.
you need to add

```
imageBitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
```

right after

```
imageBitmap.BeginInit();
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

If you get an exception when trying that, it may be because of the file access problems. I had a problem like that and it works well now using `FileStream` and an `Invoker`. No problem when the image was changed and no matter the filepath is from explorer or inside application.

**Code:**

```
 void setImageSource(string file)
    {

            using (var stream = new FileStream(
                                    file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                image.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(
                    stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Where your pathToFileDestination? is it in Debug folder or any folder created by you?

Comment: While using a FileStream instead of an Uri may be a good hint, there is absolutely no indication that using the Dispatcher (not Invoker) would be necessary here. The answer would be better without that.

Comment: @jan, As you mentioned your image source may change multiple times and you have an image object, you can follow MVVM Patern.